# UWP Download File with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, uwp

i'd wrote a download function but when the file was written on my PC it's an empty file (zero byte lenght) 
Anyone can tell me the reason ?

This is the function

```
Public Shared Async Function StartDownload(ByVal InputUrl As String, ByVal FileName As String) As Task


    Dim MioPicker As FolderPicker = New FolderPicker()
    MioPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop
    MioPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
    MioPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*")
    Dim MioFolder As StorageFolder = Await MioPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync

    Dim source As New Uri(InputUrl)

    Dim destinationFile As StorageFile = Await MioFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName)

    Dim downloader As New BackgroundDownloader()
    Dim download As DownloadOperation = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile)

End Function
```

Thank's a lots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i'd wrote a download function but when the file was written on my PC it's an 
>   empty file (zero byte lenght)

This is because you didn't start the download operation. You just [created](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader.createdownloadasync.aspx) a download operation that includes a URI will be scheduled. After then you need to start the download operation by method [DownloadOperation.StartAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.downloadoperation.startasync.aspx) . Code as follows:

```
   Dim downloader As New BackgroundDownloader()
   Dim download As DownloadOperation = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile)
   Await download.StartAsync()
```

Additionally, to attach a progress handler in your code will be much better. For how to handle a progress handle and more details please reference the [download scenario](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer/vb/BackgroundTransfer/Scenario1_Download.xaml.vb) of [background transfer official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer). And you can also reference the official [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/background-transfers#downloading-files).

Comment: Thanks a  lots . My mistake was  leave the StartAsync  line... :-(

Answer (score 1):

try the following :

> HandleDownloadAsync(download, true)

This will download the file in the backround and your programm does not have to wait for it to end .
The code snipped is in C# but should work like in vb.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207154